# Is it reasonable to expect to wait a month before receiving a new contract of employment after salary negotiation?

Tags: employment, first-job, covid-19, england, apprentice

I recently completed an apprenticeship for a company that I've been working at for three years now.

Pretty soon after I received a contract of employment from them - however the salary was too low due to a misunderstanding that I would continue my apprenticeship at a higher level. After some very brief discussions I was told that a different contract would be discussed with my manager's higher ups.

Since then it has nearly been a month and a half, About a week ago I chased and was told that one of the people responsible for the contract has contracted covid-19 - though I have seen that the person in question has been active on emails and during a weekly company call for several weeks now. Other than that there has been no news.

Is this sort of delay reasonable?
Why might it be taking so long?
Are they just trying to string me along at my current low wage for as long as possible?

Comment: How long has it been since your last chase?

Comment: Is your current wage below the minimum wage?

Comment: @motosubatsu It's been 1 week.

Comment: And no, my current wage is not below minimum wage.

Comment: Location might help, but in my experience from sweden this is not unusual. I would gently remind them on occation as long as they still pay out sallary.

Comment: I will ammend the title for accuracy:
Is it reasonable to expect to wait a month before receiving a new contract of employment after salary negotiation?

Comment: It can happen. it's not common, usually employers are in a hurry. Some of them may have reasons to delay, or lack HR manpower to do the work.

Answer (score 3):

It's hard for us to tell what's going on under the surface.

They may be stringing you along, or they may generally be impacted by COVID.

Contracts can be formed reasonably quickly. HR like to make a song and dance about it, but usually it's just tweaking a few figures on a highly standardised form.

What you should, of course, be doing is looking for other opportunities to secure your own future.